# json data reply nil

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, ipad, nsurlconnection

```
NSString *urlString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/questions?tagged=iphone & key=%d",key1];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"text/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:@"text/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

    NSError        *error ;
    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&error];
    NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"jsondata=%@,%@",json_string,response);
```

> 2011-02-11 12:01:16.653
>   mystack[1946:207] jsondata=,(null)

Comment: It seems that there is something wrong with your server's response. I suggest you NSLog your response's file length like this, **[response length]**, to check whether that NSData instance is empty or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thanks for helping me here is the answer

```
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
```

the code that i have to change..

Answer (score 4):

Your URL string is not valid since it contains blank spaces: `&`. You need to escape those before creating an `NSURL` object. Replace:

```
NSString *urlString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/questions?tagged=iphone & key=%d",key1];
```

with:

```
NSString *urlString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/questions?tagged=iphone & key=%d",key1];
urlString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should NSLog your error variable to see what happened: `[error localizedDescription]`

Comment: jsondata=,(null),0,Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL" UserInfo=0x4b65150 {NSUnderlyingError=0x4b68fd0 "bad URL", NSLocalizedDescription=bad URL}